# same file name in typescript files and javascript files

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say in the src folder, we have two files, one is typescript file `someFeatures.ts`, the other is js file  `someFeatures.js`,so their main file name is the same, and contain the same content,just the extension name is different,
so in the main `index.ts` file, I import the dependency as:

```
import { sizeFormatter, costFormatter } from "./someFeatures";
```

so how does the compile know which one I'm referring to? it could be `someFeatures.ts` or `someFeatures.js`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`allowJS: false`**

If the `allowJs` option in `tsconfig.json` is set to `false` then Typescript compiler will ignore `someFeatures.js` like any `.js` file when it resolves imports. It will take only `.ts .tsx .d.ts` into account as explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190920151820/https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) under *How TypeScript resolves modules* heading.

**`allowJS: true`**

If the `allowJs` option in `tsconfig.json` is set to `true` then Typescript compiler will specifically ignore `someFeatures.js` as a "possible output" due to presence of `someFeatures.ts`as explained [there](https://web.archive.org/web/20191002235125/https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details), search for "possible outputs".

Comment: So in both cases `someFeatures.js` will be ignored by the TS compiler? Which case is now the one that should be used when in one file the `.ts` file should be imported but in another file a `.js` import is needed?  Furthermore, there is no heading *How TypeScript resolves modules* for the first link, and searching for *possible outputs* does not find anything for the second link.

Comment: @winklerrr Yes, will be ignored in both cases. To import `.js` file (a) ensure its name doesn't conflict with a 'possible output', (b) provide an ambient declaration in a `.d.ts` file and (c) set `allowJS: true`